# CMake toolchain file: Is there a way to specify the includes and definitions syntax?

Tags: cmake

I'm using a cross compiler which uses `-inc` instead of `-I` for include paths and `-def` instead of `-D` for definitions.

How can I configure CMake to work with this toolchain?